# Update a formset instance through

Tags: django, django-forms

**the formset are stored correctly in the database, this is the code**

```
def crear_encuesta(request):
    HotelFormSet = formset_factory(HotelForm, extra=6)
    RestauranteFormSet = formset_factory(RestauranteForm, extra=6)
    if request.method == 'POST':              
        formset_restaurante = RestauranteFormSet(request.POST)
        formset_hotel = HotelFormSet(request.POST)
        if formset_restaurante.is_valid() and formset_hotel.is_valid():                

            for form in formset_restaurante.forms:
                restaurante = form.save(commit=False)
                restaurante.save()    

            for form in formset_hotel.forms:
                hotel = form.save(commit=False)          
                hotel.save()        

            messages.add_message(request, messages.SUCCESS, 'Encuesta salvada correctamente.')
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/crear_encuesta/') # Redirect after POST
    else:               
        formset_hotel = HotelFormSet()
        formset_restaurante = RestauranteFormSet()
    return render_to_response('encuestas/crear_encuesta.html',{               
        'formset_hotel':formset_hotel,
        'formset_restaurante':formset_restaurante
    },RequestContext(request))
```

**I need to edit several formset, this is my code**
this code does is create new objects, and does not modify the existing database

```
def modificar_encuesta(request):
    HotelFormSet = formset_factory(HotelForm, extra=0)
    RestauranteFormSet = formset_factory(RestauranteForm, extra=0)
    if request.method == 'POST':
      formset_restaurante = RestauranteFormSet(request.POST)
      formset_hotel = HotelFormSet(request.POST)
      if formset_restaurante.is_valid() and formset_hotel.is_valid():        

        for form in formset_restaurante.forms:
            restaurante = form.save(commit=False)
            restaurante.save()


        for form in formset_hotel.forms:
            hotel = form.save(commit=False)
            hotel.save()

        messages.add_message(request, messages.SUCCESS, 'Encuesta modificada correctamente.')
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/modificar_encuesta/')

return render_to_response('encuestas/modificar_encuesta.html',{'flag':flag},RequestContext(request))
```

**my problem is that I need to spend some instance to**

```
formset_restaurante = RestauranteFormSet(request.POST)
formset_hotel = HotelFormSet(request.POST)
```

**to modify the object in specific, but eg fails.**

I can then updated the formset as I have already saved in the database. Any help is welcome ...
I did not put all the code to simplify the example in question

Comment: do you mean to say if there are objects in the database, populate them in the formset ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can initialize your formset like this:

```
RestauranteFormSet = modelformset_factory(Restaurante, extra=2)
restaurante_formset = RestauranteFormSet(queryset=Restaurante.objects.all())
```

and `request.POST`

```
formset_restaurante = RestauranteFormSet(request.POST, queryset=Restaurante.objects.all())
```